# Apply html formatting to i18n messages

Tags: playframework-2.0

In Play! 2.0 we can pass arguments to a i18n message like this:

In my view: (message.key = task.created with arguments: firstName and a code)

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
<a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
    @Messages("task.created", MyContext.currentUser().firstName, newTask.code)
</div>
```

My message is defined as:

```
task.created=<strong>{0}</strong>, your task has been saved with code {1}
```

I would like to see the `firstName` with the HTML tag strong, but instead of applying the strong tag it just printing the `strong` tag.

I hope you understand my question. Is this possible in Play or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
@Html(Messages("task.created", MyContext.currentUser().firstName, newTask.code))
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Does this open up an XSS vulnerability if the user's first name contains HTML?

Comment: Yes, using @Html will render any content as HTML, so any of the parameters provided to Messages are XSS vulnerable.